# How to create a file in the active Directory

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

The problem I have is that the file is created in the root and I cannot find the right instruction to change to a named directory!

```
 // Create a new Spreadsheet and copy the current sheet into it.
 var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create( invNo );
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
       invtoSend.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
```

Comment: Find the folder through `DriveApp` and then use [`AddFile()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addFile(File)) to add the file to your folder.

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp` is for spreadsheet-specific tasks, not file organization. `DriveApp` is for generic file manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

just create the spreadSheet, get its ID and then use DriveApp to move it (and to remove it from root otherwise it will be available in both !)

```
 var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create( invNo );
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId());
 DriveApp.getFolderById('0B3°°°°°°°1lXWkk').addFile( file );
 DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file);
```

### EDIT

I reallize that your question can be understood differently : you might want that the destination folder would be the "current spreadsheet" folder, in this case here is the appropriate code :

```
function xxxx(){
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create( "invNo" );
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId());
  var folders = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()).getParents();
  while(folders.hasNext()){ // a file might be in multiple folders, include it in all of them except root
    var folder = folders.next();
    if(folder.getName()!=DriveApp.getRootFolder().getName()){  // root folder name changes with user's locale
      folder.addFile(file);
      DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file);
      Logger.log('destination folder name = '+folder.getName());
    }
  }
}
```